# How to accept only xsd file in html input tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can I show only XSD files in a file input element? I tried like this

```
<input type="file" accept="text/xsd" >
```

But is not working , its allowing all file formats .

Comment: _"show only XSD files"_ - but you're using an input? What do you mean by "show"? What is the goal here?

Answer (score 0):

The way the constraints are specified is not correct. It should be like this:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".xsd" >
```